# Python float counter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column which has floats and missing values example

```
1,2
11,2,34
nan
```

I would like to create another column which will count these numbers
so

```
1,2      2
11,2,34  3
nan      0
```

Comment: And what is your current state? How did you start working on it? On SO no one will implement you a working solution, you will only get some help building your own solution ;)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It is unclear to me what you are working with exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest is remove `NaN`s by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and count `,` by [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['new'] = df['W'].fillna('').str.count(',')
print (df)
         W  new
0      1,2    1
1  11,2,34    2
2      NaN    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I came up with this answer after few minutes
v=df['VV']
'''
def v_counter(x):
    x=str(x)
    try:
        if x=='nan':
            x=''
        else:
            x=x.split(',')
    except:
        none
    return len(x)
'''
Thanks for checking
```

Comment: What's this? What is `df['VV']`? Why is the method in a multi-line-string, and where is it called? What is `none`? And why do you convert to string? You can use `math.isnan` or `np.isnan`.